# hyperref autoref capitalization problems with babel

Tags: hyperref, babel

I have already read some similar qustions, but the solution over there does not work if I add the 'babel' package. The thing is change the autorefname of one specific, say Figure, and I just want to change the way that it is written, say capital case. Everything is fine but if I uncomment the package babel, so the command is ignored.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\figureautorefname{FIGURE}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
As shown in \autoref{fig:foo}~\dots
\end{document}
```

probably is a easy questions, but I don't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) of `hyperref` contains an example for this case:

> Example for a redefinition if babel is used:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
> \addto\extrasngerman{%  
>   \def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}%  
> }
> ```

In your case:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\figureautorefname{FIGURE}%
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work, I have already seen the example in the manual, and it works perfectly, but changing the language as well as the command extrasngerman by captionsenglish, it does not.

Comment: Answer fixed: `\extrasenglish` instead of `\captionsenglish`.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution somewhere else. Its is correct what the manual tells you but the redefinition have to be place directly after the import of the href package!

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{href} 
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}}
```

worked for me.
Greetings

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you mean to refer to the `hyperref` package instead of the `href` package?