# No autoref name for `Appendix'

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I get the following warning in LaTeX while trying to automatically refer via `\autoref{}` to a label in my appendix.

```
No autoref name for `Appendix'
```

I guess it is trying to tell me that it has no label defined for appendix, funny because it directly displays me the name I’d like to have which it doesn’t output; it’s simply blank.

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \autoref{a:entry}

  \begin{appendices}
    \section{Entry}
    \label{a:entry}
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command for the label with uppercase letter is not defined and that’s why the `hyperref` package is complaining. You have to define the command yourself:

```
\newcommand*{\Appendixautorefname}{Appendix}
```

Include this after loading the `hyperref` package and before beginning the actual document and it should work just fine.

Comment: Does not work for me. Apprently this is due to `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` (it works with `\usepackage[english]{babel}`). Any idea how to get this solved? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Addition: Also using `\addto\extrasngerman{  \def\Appendixautorefname{Anhang}}` or `\addto\extrasngerman{  \def\appendixautorefname{Anhang}}` as described in [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/hyperref-autoref-capitalization-problems-with-babel] does not help.

Comment: Addition 2: Like @ted assumed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130096/autoref-to-appendix-with-appendix-package I just discovered that this has also to do something with the `appendix` package. Still did not find a solution, though ...

Comment: Addition 3: Opened a separate Question for this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299675/no-autorefname-for-appendices-when-using-babel-with-ngerman-and-appendix-package

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149807/autoref-subsections-in-appendix For dealing with Appendix Sections and Subsections.