# No autorefname for appendices when using babel with ngerman and appendix package

Tags: hyperref, babel, appendices, tocloft, autoref

When using the `appendix` package together with `[ngerman]{babel}` changing `appendixautorefname` or `Appendixautorefname` has no effect.

The error message `No autoref name for 'Anhang' [...]` persists.

How do I get this to work?

Thanks a lot in advance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasngerman{%
    \def\chapterautorefname{Kapitel}%
    \def\appendixautorefname{Anhang}%
    \def\Appendixautorefname{Anhang}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{a}\label{ch:a}
Reference to chapter: \autoref{ch:a}

Reference to appendix: \autoref{App}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Ein Anhang}\label{App}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I already asked this question(s) in the comment section of [No autoref name for `Appendix'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207744/no-autoref-name-for-appendix/207745#comment725437_207745) but felt better opening a new Question for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why `\Appendixautorefname` isn't working is that `tocloft` uses the `\appendixname` macro to create the anchor `Anhang` here, see the entry

```
\newlabel{App}{{A}{3}{Ein Anhang}{Anhang.a.A}{}}
```

in the `.aux` file. `hyperref` is looking then for a special `\Anhangautorefname` command, not `\Appendixautorefname`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\addto\extrasngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Kapitel}%
  \renewcommand{\appendixautorefname}{\appendixname}%
  \@ifundefined{Anhangautorefname}{%
    \newcommand{\Anhangautorefname}{\appendixname}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand{\Anhangautorefname}{\appendixname}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{a}\label{ch:a}
Reference to chapter: \autoref{ch:a}

Reference to appendix: \autoref{App}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Ein Anhang}\label{App}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Grodon: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed my issue (similair, but for french) with a subset of your answer ```\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixautorefname}{\appendixname}%
}
\makeatother```