# How do I change the list of listings title font and list of listings entry spacing?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, listings, tocloft

I've set some formatting in my table of contents, list of tables, and list of figures that I want to continue in my list of listings (using [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package). However, I can't find the commands to do so. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,left=1.25in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code} %change 'listing' to 'code'
%
%
\begin{document}
%
%Adjusted the font of the list of listings title
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{\centering\bfseries\normalsize{LIST OF CODE}}
%
\lstlistoflistings
\vspace{1in}
%
%test listings
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=exlist]
test code
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=exlist2]
test code 2
\end{lstlisting}
%
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: compilation result]

I want to do a few things.

1) I want to control the distance from the top margin to the LIST OF CODE title similar to `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{1in}` in `tocloft`. Is there a way to do this with the listings package?
Update: This distance is controlled by `tocloft`. Thus, use `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{\spaceBeforeChapterTitles}`.

2) I want to control the vskip between the LIST OF CODE title and the first line similar to `\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{12pt}` in `tocloft`.
Update: This distance is controlled by `tocloft` as well. Thus, use
`\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{\spaceBetweenTitleAndText}`.

3) I want to control the vskip values in between the list of listings entries (i.e. 12pt skip between exlist and exlist2 lines) like I do with `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{12pt}` in `tocloft`.

4) I want to control the space between dots, similar to `\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1.5}` in `tocloft`.

5) I want there to be a space between listings that come from different chapters, just as is done automatically in a list of figures or list of tables.

I think I may be able to create a new list of code using `tocloft`, but I really like how `listings` color codes my scripts.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `\listoflistings` settings can't be controlled with `tocloft` that way.

Comment: Any news here? Did you try to adjust it in another way?

Comment: No, I gave up for now. I'll have to come back to it eventually though and I'll see if I remember to give an update here.

Comment: update: I discovered that #1 and #2 are controlled by the tocloft settings. Thus, the following commands will also change the list of listings: `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{\spaceBeforeChapterTitles}`. However, I'm still looking for solutions for #3, #4, and I'm adding #5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've combed various forums and come up with a solution that works to address all five questions. Please see the code below for comments and explanations.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,left=1.25in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead}



\usepackage{tocloft} %allow us to change some of the table contents, list of (whatever)
\usepackage{caption}

%Found a nice reference here: https://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/
%Let's define a new list called List of Code
\newlistof{code}{loc}{\MakeUppercase{List of Code}}
%{id of list}{abbreviation for the list}{name of list}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Answer to Question #1 and #2. %%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Control the spacing before and after the title with the following commands,
%analogous to how we control the spacing in toc.
\setlength{\cftbeforeloctitleskip}{1in}
\setlength{\cftafterloctitleskip}{1in}

%Format the title of the list. Center with an \hfill on either side
\renewcommand{\cftloctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftafterloctitle}{\hfill\space}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Answer to Question #3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Adjust the vskip before each new list entry with the following:
\setlength{\cftbeforecodeskip}{.5\normalbaselineskip}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Answer to Question #4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%set the distance between TOC dots (default 4.5) with the following:
\renewcommand{\cftcodedotsep}{1.5} 



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Answer to Question #5 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% a quick patch so a space is added between chapters (like is done in toc, lof, lot)
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461521/how-to-create-space-between-chapter-in-list-of-listings
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\addtocontents}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{loc}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Add per-chapter space in LoL
   \addtocontents}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
%end of patch



% Note that all the changes we've made have been separate from the listings package.
% We will be using our own caption system based on a new environment instead of 
% using a caption system for lstlistings.
% Let's now make the new environment.
\newenvironment{coding}[1]{% require one input (the caption)
\refstepcounter{code} %increase the counter. Note that we reset it later (per chapter)
%
%
% now format the environment
\par %make sure it starts on a new line
\vspace{\baselineskip} %this was previously taken care of with \lstset, but we need
% to manually add it here to have the space be above our custom caption.
\noindent\textbf{Code \thechapter.\thecode: #1} %format the caption
\addcontentsline{loc}{code} %add entry to the list of code
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thecode}#1}
\par}%
{} %Nothing special needs to happen in closing the environment.


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{code}{chapter} %reset the list of code counter at each new chapter
\renewcommand{\p@code}{\thechapter.} % Want \autoref to include the chapter number.
\makeatother


\usepackage{listings} % minted is also an option, but I wanted to stick with 
% listings because it seems to be updated more regularly.
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{% define my own style. Lots of options to choose from.
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=t, %caption position t or b
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle} %set the new style
\lstset{%aboveskip=\baselineskip, %don't want this aboveskip because it would put a 
% space between our custom caption and the code.
belowskip=\baselineskip}


%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207744/no-autoref-name-for-appendix
\usepackage{hyperref} %for referencing the code
\newcommand*{\codeautorefname}{Code}



\begin{document}


\listofcode


\chapter{The First Chapter}
I've written some sample code in \autoref{code1}. I hope you enjoy!


\begin{coding}{This is my new environment caption}
\label{code1} %Include the label for cross referencing here.

%This example would insert an entire matlab script.
%I'm commenting it out for simplicity of posting here.
% \lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,%
% % caption=SigmaExtract.m,%      Don't include the caption here.
% % label={code:SigmaExtract},%   Don't include label here.
% ]{SigmaExtract.m} 

%Instead, I'll show a simple portion of script here:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=matlab]
function TestFunction()
%%% This is a sample function.

for i = 1:10
    fprintf('i = %0.0f\n',i)
end; clear i

end
\end{lstlisting}

\end{coding}


\begin{coding}{The second coding section}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=matlab]
function TestFunction()
%%% This is another sample function.

disp('Hello World')

end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{coding}


\chapter{Even more great content}

\begin{coding}{The third great function}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=matlab]
function j = TestFunction(i)
%%% This is another sample function.

j = i+1;

end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{coding}

\end{document}
```

The List of Code (Page 1):
[image: List of Code (Page 1)]

Some sample code with demonstration of `\autoref` (Page 2)
[image: Sample code with reference (Page 2)]

Last page for completeness (Page 3)
[image: Last page for completeness (Page 3)]

Comment: Note that solution for #5 doesn't work if you're using the `newfloat` package in your document.