# How to create space between chapter in List of Listings

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, listings

I want space in the List of Algorithm for every chapter that I insert, similar to how it occurs in the List of Figures and List of Tables.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algoritmo}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Indice de \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings
%\listofmyequations
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{First section}
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
x=a+b
};
\end{lstlisting}
[lipsum]
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
x=a+b
};
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{second chapter}
\section{First section}
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= Algoritmo  hiperparametros]
x=a+b
};
\end{lstlisting}
```

I want like it to look like this example, but for my algorithms:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With every call to `\chapter`, the [`book` class](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) inserts a space in the LoF and LoT via an indirect call to `\@chapter`:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Note the calls

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
```

above which inserts `\addvspace{10\p@}` into the `.lof` and `.lot` files. All you need to do is insert

```
\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
```

to add the same space in the `.lol` (for List of Listings). This is achievable via a patch to `\@chapter` (thanks to [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

[image]

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\addtocontents}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Add per-chapter space in LoL
   \addtocontents}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Comment: goood answer, a question more please, for the index of figures or tables the spacing is by default, because for algorithms it is not?

Comment: @hubman: Yes, because figures and tables are more common than algorithms.