# Can the space between elements of the "List of Listings" be changed, so that appears like table of figures/tables?

Tags: listings, overleaf

When adding the 'List of Listings' to the Table of Contents (as shown in the image where I have customized the title), I noticed that there was no space between the list elements when the chapter changes, unlike the list of figures and tables. Here are the differences:

[image: Image of the list of figures]

[image: Image of the list of listings]

As you can see, there is no space between entries when the chapter changes.

I tried `\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em}`, where 3em is just an example of spacing, but it gave me an error that it's already defined, when I did not defined myself. Right now the code for customizing the listings is this:

````
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Codice}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{Elenco dei codici sorgenti} 
\counterwithin*{listing}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thelisting{\thechapter.\arabic{listing}}```
````

Here’s an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\listingscaption{Codice}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{Elenco dei codici sorgenti}
\counterwithin*{listing}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thelisting{\thechapter.\arabic{listing}}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}  % Numbering depth for sections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}     
% Depth of entries in the table of contents

\tableofcontents
%\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}
\clearpage

\begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax

    % Figures list
    \phantomsection
    \pdfbookmark{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \listoffigures

    \vspace*{8ex}

    % Listings list
    \phantomsection
    \pdfbookmark{\listoflistingscaption}{lol}
    \listoflistings

    \vspace*{8ex}
\endgroup

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    print("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of code in Chapter 1}
\label{listing:1}
\end{listing}

\section{Introduzione al progetto}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[alt={Testo alternativo dell'immagine}, width=0.5\columnwidth]{img/pk_estate.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pk_estate}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    print("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of another code in Chapter 1}
\label{listing:2}
\end{listing}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Introduzione al progetto}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[alt={Testo alternativo dell'immagine}, width=0.5\columnwidth]{img/pk_estate.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pk_etate}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduzione al progetto}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[alt={Testo alternativo dell'immagine}, width=0.5\columnwidth]{img/pk_estate.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pk_estate2-2}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    print("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of code in Chapter 2}
\label{listing:3}
\end{listing}

% More chapters and listings...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Benvenuto! A small sample of code is needed.

Comment: Hi. I have added the basic structure of my project. It is organized into multiple files and then compiled together in the "thesis.tex" file. I have included the basic configuration files and a simple usage of the code block, along with the creation of the document itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create space between chapter in List of Listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461521/5764)

Comment: BTW: With `scrbook` instead of `book` the wanted space happens already automatically (as long, as you don't break it with packages like `titlesec`).

Comment: @Gvnn Sorry, but that's far from minimal. Please, show the class and remove all unnecessary packages, adding some minimal text (not `\input` instructions) that can show the issue.

Comment: @egreg I’ve updated the example, so now the file shows the issue. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject similar code as `\@chapter` does, that inserts vertical spaces in the “list of” auxiliary files when a new chapter starts.

The code below works whether `hyperref` or not is loaded. The problem is that if `hyperref` is loaded, the command to patch is `\NR@chapter` and not `\@chapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\NR@chapter
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi{\patchcmd\NR@chapter}{\patchcmd\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
   \addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\listingscaption{Codice}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{Elenco dei codici sorgenti}
\counterwithin*{listing}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thelisting{\thechapter.\arabic{listing}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    print("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of code in Chapter 1}
\label{listing:1}
\end{listing}

\section{Introduzione al progetto}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
    \centering 
%    \includegraphics[alt={Testo alternativo dell'immagine}, width=0.5\columnwidth]{img/pk_estate.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pk_estate}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    print("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of another code in Chapter 1}
\label{listing:2}
\end{listing}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Introduzione al progetto}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
    \centering 
%    \includegraphics[alt={Testo alternativo dell'immagine}, width=0.5\columnwidth]{img/pk_estate.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pk_etate}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduzione al progetto}
\begin{figure}[!ht] 
    \centering 
%    \includegraphics[alt={Testo alternativo dell'immagine}, width=0.5\columnwidth]{img/pk_estate.jpeg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pk_estate2-2}
\end{figure}

\begin{listing}[!ht]
\begin{minted}{c}
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    print("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of code in Chapter 2}
\label{listing:3}
\end{listing}

% More chapters and listings...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you very much!!